Touchscreen Functionality Crashing on Rapid Touch in .NET Maui Hybrid App
if I rapidly click anywhere inside the app while starting up and loading, the touchsrceen will be broken but the mouse is still working.
Steps to Reproduce
Create a new Maui Blazor Project
Deploy it on any tablet
Repeatly touch the screen inside the app window as quickly as you can

Did this problem only appear on windows tablet?

yes only in windows tablet
